# How do I configure pdm for a src-based Python repository?

Tags: python, pyproject.toml, python-pdm

I have previously arranged a Python repository without a `src` folder, and got it running with:

```
pdm install --dev
pdm run mymodule
```

I am failing to replicate the process in a repository *with* a `src` folder. How do I do it?

**pyproject.toml**

```
[project]
name = "mymodule"
version = "0.1.0"
description = "Minimal Python repository with a src layout."
requires-python = ">=3.10"

[build-system]
requires = ["pdm-pep517>=1.0.0"]
build-backend = "pdm.pep517.api"

[project.scripts]
mymodule = "cli:invoke"
```

**src/mymodule/__init__.py**

Empty file.

**src/mymodule/cli.py**

```
def invoke():
    print("Hello world!")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    invoke()
```

With the configuration above, I can `pdm install --dev` but `pdm run mymodule` fails with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/user/Documents/mymodule/.venv/bin/mymodule", line 5, in <module>
    from cli import invoke
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cli'
```

Comment: This is not what I would call a `src`-layout. In a `src` layout there definitely should not be any `__init__.py` in the `src` directory. Because that would mean that `src` is an importable package (as in `import src`), which goes against the whole point of the `src`-layout in the first place.

Comment: @sinoroc doh! that was a transcription error on my part, fixed

Comment: Still... the way this question is formulated is confusing to me, it mixes two different things into one. From my point of view it has nothing to do with `src` layout or not. It has to do with restructuring the package structure by moving the `cli` module into a `mypackage` package. You could have a `src` layout while still keeping `cli` as a top-level module without moving it into a `mypackage` package`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to modify your **pyproject.toml** as follows:

```
[project.scripts]
mymodule = "mymodule.cli:invoke"
```

For good measure, you may want to delete the **.venv** folder and **.pdm.toml** file before running `pdm install --dev` again.

Comment: Hi! Do you have the reference for this? Where did you learn this?

Comment: I learnt by bashing my head against it :D the references for pyprojects and scripts are a bit scattered - there is a good authoritative one but I don't have the handy :( - I maintain a barebones project https://gitlab.com/lfdo/mini/tcarlae that I update occasionally as I learn